# How to show featured image in custom post type dashboard post page

Tags: posts, customization

I have added this code to my theme to add a new colmum for showing the featured image in  the dashboard post page colmum. It's working in wordpress default post page, but not in custom post type (my custom post name is photo_gallery).

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_columns', 5);
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns', 5, 3);
function posts_columns($defaults){
    $defaults['riv_post_thumbs'] = __('Thumbnail');
    return $defaults;
}
function posts_custom_columns($column_name, $id){
   if($column_name === 'riv_post_thumbs'){
        echo the_post_thumbnail( array('292, 292') );
    }
}
```

How can I show this custom column as first in my custom post type overview?

Comment: Put your code in backticks please. Use the {} for code when adding code in your question

Comment: What is backtricks.I can not understand.I put my code between {} but it show nothing.

Comment: @PieterGoosen talks about the buttons right above the text editor field. One button symbolize two bracket »{}«. Click on the button, and the editor prepares the code-input for you. (Which is just an indentation of for spaces). To mark up inline-code you should wrap it in »Backticks« (or »Back quotes«): ```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what exactly does not work for your custom post type. There are two possible cases:

- Your custom post type `photo_gallery` is hierarchical. That would mean, neither (column head and values) are shown.
- Your post type is not hierarchical but does not support featured images.

Anyway, if you want to add the thumbnail *only* to your custom post type this code should do it:

```
add_filter( 'manage_photo_gallery_posts_columns', 'wpse_135433_posts_columns' );
add_action( 'manage_photo_gallery_posts_custom_column', 'wpse_135433_posts_custom_columns', 10, 2 );

function wpse_135433_posts_columns( $defaults ){

    $defaults = array_merge(
        array( 'riv_post_thumbs' => __( 'Thumbnail' ) ),
        $defaults
    );

    return $defaults;
}

function wpse_135433_posts_custom_columns( $column_name, $id ) {

   if ( $column_name === 'riv_post_thumbs' ) {
        echo the_post_thumbnail( array('292, 292') );
    }
}
```

By the way, you should use prefixes on your custom functions to avoid collisions. (In this example I used the prefix `wpse_135433_`.

The function `wpse_135433_posts_columns()` attaches the column at the first position to the list of columns `$defaults`.

If you want to use this functionality on more than your custom post type you should use

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'wpse_135433_posts_columns', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'wpse_135433_posts_custom_columns', 10, 2 );
```

for non hierarchical post types and

```
add_filter( 'manage_pages_columns', 'wpse_135433_posts_columns', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column', 'wpse_135433_posts_custom_columns', 10, 2 );
```

for hierarchical post types. The second parameter passed to the `manage_posts_columns` filter is the current post type.